# Xcode source control wrong username on github

Tags: xcode, git, github

Im having a problem, where I have entered my remote repository and committed the project. But when I look at the commit on Github it shows that the commit has come from a separate user, and not mine. It seems to have used the name of my developer account as the Git username, even if I have entered the correct username when setting up the repository in Github.

Is there a solution, so that when I commit from xcode, it shows up as coming from my Github profile, and not a separate account?

Comment: Is your question still unanswered?

Comment: Si, Ive been playing around with some settings and cant really get github or xcode to cooperate at all.

Comment: I've updated my answer.  Give the `xcrun` commands a try from Terminal, and see if that solves the issue!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

GitHub uses the email address in the commit header to link the commit to a GitHub user.

Xcode <s>pulls</s> used to pull your email details from Contacts.  <s>If you have multiple email addresses associated with your own contact card, Xcode is choosing a different email address to use that doesn't match your Github username email.</s>

<s>I don't believe there's a way to specify which email address to use within Xcode, but you can specify it in a local or global Git configuration file.</s>

**Update:**

Try these commands, to provide Xcode with your git username and email:

```
xcrun git config --local user.name 'new_user_name'
xcrun git config --local user.email 'new@email.com'
```

Answer (score 4):

Try deleting and re-adding the repository with correct github credentials.

Under Preferences->Accounts.

Comment: I have done that, the weird thing is that I have entered my Github username, and the credentials are fine. But when I push to the repo it does so under my full name.

Comment: Credentials let you access the repo, but aren't the source for contact details.

Answer (score 2):

Had this problem when I changed my github username in Xcode 9. The only way I could change the login credentials when committing or pushing my files was through this method.

For Xcode 9: Go to Xcode-> Preferences-> Accounts. Under "Source Control Accounts", delete your github account that is saved there and re-create it. If it isn't obvious, use the - or + sign to delete or create a new one.

Seems pretty simple, yet I couldn't figure it out for hours. Might run into a few issues you have to kink out with resetting, but it was the only thing that worked. I personally didn't have any issues.

Comment: I have the same issue but my GitHub account is greyed out and impossible to remove. Adding any source control account is impossible. Everything is greyed out and marked "Unavailable". What can I do?

Comment: @NeeratheWildMage - did the `xcrun` method not work from the accepted A'er?

Comment: The —local was not working in any case because it was asking me to be in a specific repository while the issue is a global one. I tried that xcrun with —global and it stalled after setting the email. But git config worked seemlessly...

Answer (score 1):

Okay an easier way is to go to settings in the your GitHub account > Developer settings > Personal Access tokens. Generate token, copy clipboard then paste this token in the add account section of your system preferences and boom! That's it. Instead of your password, replace with the token.

Answer (score 0):

Write these commands in terminal :-

```
$ git config --global user.name "User Name"
$ git config --global user.email "user@email"
```